# Is $L$ regular? context free but not regular? Neither? $L = \{ xwx : x,w \in \{a,b,c \}^*, |x| > 0\}$

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

I need to determine whether $L$ is regular or at least context-free. 
$$L = \{ xwx : x,w \in \{a,b,c \}^*, |x| > 0\}$$
My initial guess is that it is regular.

I think that $L$ is context free. I have come up with a simple grammar, yet I am not sure if that's the way to go:

$$S \rightarrow  a\text{Any}a | b\text{Any}b | c\text{Any}c $$
$$Any \rightarrow a | b | c | aAnya |aAnyb|aAnyc|bAnya | \ldots |\epsilon$$

Is it a potentialyl good grammar?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the intersection of $L$ with the language for the regex $a b^* c^* a b^*$ requires equal numbers of $b$ on both sides, which thus wouldn't be regular by a pumping lemma argument.  I'm not familiar enough with the context-free pumping lemma to say anything about that, but my intuition is that I don't see much hope of creating an LR parser for $L$, for example.

Comment: @DanielSchepler the word that you provided indeed works with the pumping lemma for regular languages, but it fails for context-free languages

Comment: But $ab^pcab^p$ seems to work with Ogden's lemma

Comment: I now realize the intersection of $L$ with $a b^* c^* a b^*$ is $\{ a b^m c^n a b^\ell \mid m \ge \ell \vee \ell = 0 \}$ - which still isn't regular.  (Or, you could modify it to the intersection with $a b^* c a b^* c$ which does work out to $\{ a b^n c a b^n c \}$.)

Comment: How about this: if $L$ were context free, then the intersection with the language for $a^+ b^+ a^+ b^+$ would also be context free, but this intersection would be $\{ a^d b^e a^f b^g \mid 1\le d \le f, e \ge g\ge 1 \}$.  Then, applying the CFG pumping lemma on this intersection language and word $a^p b^p a^p b^p$ should give a contradiction I think - the only opportunity I see for "positive pumping" is with $v = b^\ell$, $x = a^m$ in the middle but then "one negative pumping" ($n = 0$) won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L$ is not context free (and in fact, the version of $L$ with only two symbols is also not context free).

To show this, I will use the generalized condition under [the Wikipedia page for Ogden's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogden%27s_lemma) with $e = 3$ and $d = 16p + 5 \ge p(e+1)$, and apply it to the word $a^{4p+2} b^{4p+2} a^{4p+2} b^{4p+2}$ with excluded positions being the start of the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th blocks and all other positions being distinguished.  Now, the excluded positions will ensure that each of $v, x$ stays within one of the blocks, while the condition that $vwx$ has at most $p(e+1) = 4p$ distinguished positions ensures that $v$ and $x$ are either in the same block or in adjacent blocks.  It now remains to check in each case that either $u v^0 w x^0 y$ or $u v^2 w x^2 y$ is not in $L$, giving a contradiction.  (It will be useful in each case to use the observation that if $k_1, k_4 > 0$, then $a^{k_1} b^{k_2} a^{k_3} b^{k_4} \in L$ if and only if $k_3 \ge k_1$ and $k_2 \ge k_4$.)

To illustrate one of these cases, let us suppose that $v = b^k$ from the second block and $x = a^\ell$ from the third block.  Then $u v^0 w x^0 y = a^{4p+2} b^{4p+2 - k} a^{4p+2-\ell} b^{4p+2} \notin L$ by the above observation, since $vx$ cannot be empty so either $k > 0$ or $\ell > 0$.